# shap value of a shuffled feature

Tags: shapley-value

Imagine I have a model to predict a 100 target values `y` based on 10 features stored in a `X` table (100 by 10). Similarly to what Boruta does, I take a copy of the first feature, shuffle it randomly and append it to my original `X` table under the name `shadow_1`. My new table `X'` is now of dimension 100 by 11. I learn the model `y = f(X')` and estimate the shap values. Am I right to expect the following?

1. the expected shap values of `shadow_1` to be zero,
2. a t-test of `shap(feature_1) - shap(shadow_1)` should be significantly different from zero only if `feature_1` contribution to predicting `y` is better than noise.

I am asking this question because when I implemented this, both hypothesis are wrong and I am wondering why.

Comment: (1) Shapley values are statistics, and like any other statistic, a finite random sample may not achieve the true value. (2) t-tests, like all statistical tests, have error rates.

Comment: I should have clarified that I am not expecting exactly zero, and that in my experiment the table is much, much larger.